# C# AWS3 Get Object URL, not signed url

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

I am trying to figure out how to get a public url to an object in one of my buckets. Everything in the bucket is public, so I do not want to restrict access by a signed url, I just need to generate a URL for the object after it is uploaded to save the URL in a database for future use. Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

If you are using AWS SDK then just set the object acl to public read. Just like below

```
object.acl = :public_read
```

Comment: how does that give me the url? i want to return objects url... how do i get that?